# Upgraded ext.kotlin_version then a plugin broke

Tags: flutter

I had to update ext.kotlin_version inside build.gradle to 1.9.10 (the latest), it was 1.6.10 before, for one plugin I am using, and this broke another plugin, I am not sure how to find out a solution to this

```
e: file:///Users/.../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_app_minimizer-0.0.2/android/src/main/kotlin/dev/codecity/flutter_app_minimizer/FlutterAppMinimizerPlugin.kt:34:33 Type mismatch: inferred type is DartExecutor? but BinaryMessenger was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_app_minimizer:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```